# loops with replace within a variable

Tags: stata

I have a variable in Stata for year of birth. Some values are 77, 1986, 66, 2000, 88, 99, 70, 1995 so I need to replace values such as 88, 70, 66 to be 1988,1970,1966 and so on.

How should I do this in Stata using loops?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a loop for this. If all your two-digit dates were 19xx, you could just use:

```
replace year = year + 1900 if year < 100
```

If some of your dates are 20xx, you need to make a judgment call as to which 2-digit dates you will assign to the 2000s, and which to the 1900s. For example if you used 2023 as the cutoff (so 23 gets assigned as 2023, while 24 gets assigned as 1924) then you could do the following:

```
replace year = year + 1900 if year < 100 & year > 23
replace year = year + 2000 if year < 100 & year <= 23
```

If other centuries are possible (e.g. 1800s) then you need to figure out some other way to classify as 2-digit year is not informative enough by itself!

The above assumes your `year` variable is stored as a numeric variable. If it's a string there are other ways of doing this, but it might be simpler to just `destring` it first and then do the above operation.

Comment: I agree. It's important to underline that no loop is needed, except insofar as `replace` will automatically loop over observations and make changes as needed.